# Longitude of knot

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

[image]

I am trying to understand the peripheral system of knot. In that direction, I don't see why the description of longitude of knot in Remark 3.13 does actually lie second commutator as shown in proposition 3.12?

Answer (score 0):

Let me first just explain why it is that this word $\ell$ corresponds to the longitude.  A longitude is any peripheral curve (i.e, a curve lying on the torus boundary of the knot exterior) that is the boundary of a Seifert surface.  What characterizes these curves is that they are parallel to the knot and have linking number $0$ with it.

In the following, I drew a blue curve that is the longitude.  Every time the curve goes under an arc of the knot, I labeled the event with which Wirtinger presentation generator this corresponds to.  Collecting these generators, you get the word $\ell$.

[image: The longitude]

The linking number of a Wirtinger presentation word with a knot is the sum of the exponents.  The sum here is $0$, so the linking number is $0$.

A way to explain why longitudes are in the second commutator subgroup is thinking in terms of homology (this is some of the essence of 3.12).  Let $K$ be the knot and $G=\pi_1(S^3-K)$ its knot group.  The first homology group $H_1(S^3-K)$ is isomorphic to the abelianization of $G$, hence it is isomorphic to $G/G^{(1)}$ where $G^{(1)}$ is the first commutator subgroup.  One can check that this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ (for instance, via the Wirtinger presentation).  The function of a Seifert surface $S$ of $K$ is that given an element of $G$ represented as a smooth curve in $S^3-K$, its value in $G/G^{(1)}$ can be evaluated through calculating the algebraic intersection number of the curve with $S$.

Given an element of $G$ whose curve can be put purely on $S$, by pushing it off the surface in one direction, we see it intersects with $S$ zero times.  Hence, such elements lie in $G^{(1)}$.  Similarly, the longitude is a word that lies on $S$, so it lies in $G^{(1)}$.  However, something special happens.  Since the boundary of $S$ is a word that is a composition of commutators of the canonical system of curves of $S$, it lies in the second commutator subgroup $G^{(2)}$.

This is saying that the longitude is not only zero in $H_1(S^3-K)$, but zero in $H_1(\overline{S^3-K})$, where $\overline{S^3-K}$ denotes the covering space associated to $G^{(1)}$ (the "infinite cyclic cover").  $H_1(\overline{S^3-K})$ is isomorphic to the abelianization of the commutator subgroup, i.e., $G^{(1)}/G^{(2)}$.

Comment: Nice. But i was just wondering why s_1^{-1}s_2^{-1}s_3^{-1}s_4^{-1}s_5^{-1}s_5^{5} this won't work as a word for longitude from Wirtinger presentation?

Comment: @RiyaSharma You have written down an element of the commutator subgroup (i.e., the linking number of the loop for that word with the knot is $0$) -- but why are you suggesting that it is a word representing the boundary of a Seifert surface?  Something I'll add is that the collection of longitudes for a knot as words in $G$ consists of a single conjugacy class.  Are you saying this word you've written is conjugate to $\ell$?

Comment: Boundary of a  Seifert Surface is the knot right, that's why i am suspecting if going along the knot with the described word is also longitude or not?

Comment: @RiyaSharma Do you understand how they constructed this particular $\ell$? Each generator is from when the longitude passes under a strand (demonstrating this is the purpose of my illustration).  I can help more if you explain where this word is coming from and why you think it corresponds to the boundary of a Seifert surface.